# Strange issue with HTML / CSS causing extra space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with some unexplained space at the bottom of a page that I am working on.  I have tried to fix the issue but I can't figure out what is causing it...

A screenshot of the problem is here: http://bit.ly/18FQ9Ca

A link to the real page is here: http://bit.ly/18FR1qA

I think it might be something to do with the `id="CivilService"` div layer, as the problem goes away when I remove the div.  But there doesn't seem to be anything contained which could cause the problem.

Many thanks for any help that you can give...

**EDIT**

The issues seems related jQuery not correctly setting the hight of `.wrapper-holder` using this code

```
var footerHeight = $('.footer-wrapper').height();
var main_body_height = doc_height - footerHeight;
$("div.wrapper-holder").height(main_body_height);
```

This exact code seems to be working fine on other pages of the site, does anyone know what could be causing the problem on this page?

Many thanks for your continued help...

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: Thanks @j08691 I will get the relevant bits of the code and edit the question...

Comment: Removing the line-height in the .footer-new style seems to sit the text against the green if that's what the issue is?

Comment: Thanks for this @DarrenCrabb  The issue is that there is look much green at the bottom of the page, In fact the `.wrapper-holder` div should end immediately above the grey footer.  It seems that something is causing the jQuery to make `wrapper-holder` longer than it should be.  Strange...

Comment: @j08691  I have amended this question and added code as it seems this issue is more related to jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a height on wrapper-holder

```
<div class="wrapper-holder" style="height: 1458px;">

</div>
```

Remove this height or set a smaller height to remove the spacing at the bottom

Comment: Thanks for this @Sromero  I see what you mean about the `wrapper-holder` being too tall, whereas the `.wrapper-holder` div should end immediately above the grey footer.  It seems that something is causing the jQuery to make `wrapper-holder` longer than it should be.  Strange...

Comment: This does solve the problem, hence marking this as the correct answer.  I have made a new question to cover the issue with jQuery not setting the footer height correctly.

Comment: May i suggest adding a clear class under box right as this may resolve the issue i wasn't able to test though because the dom had all ready been loaded.